# Iterating with different set of random reals at each iteration

Tags: random, core-language, iterators

```
ClearAll[f]
For[i = 1, i <= 20, i++,  
  f[x_, y_, z_] := 2 x + y + z;  
  data = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {i, 3}];  
  mapping = Map[f @@ # &, data]  
  mapping[[i]]]
```

In the above code, I want to run the loop 20 times, each time with different sets of random numbers, and finally print out the 20 values in the form of `mapping [[i]]`. Clearly I am not achieving that. Can anyone help me please?

Comment: missing `;` before the last `mapping`, also, `For` does not return so you need `Print`.

Comment: Now about logic, each time you generate `i` rows, map every one but use only `i-th`, was that the goal?

Comment: Check `Table[f @@ RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 3], 20]` or `f @@@ RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {20, 3}]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
f[x_, y_, z_] := 2 x + y + z;
```

You really don't want to use looping constructs to evaluate `f` over 20 sets of randoms arguments. Mathematica has better tools for doing that kind of thing.

The [`Table`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Table.html) function is one first functions beginners should learn about, so I recommend Kuba'a suggestion:

```
SeedRandom[42]; m = Table[f @@ RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 3], 20];
```

A somewhat more advanced approach is (also mentioned by Kuba):

```
SeedRandom[42]; m = f @@@ RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {20, 3}];
```

In both cases

```
m // Column
```

gives

[image: result]

Note: You can omit the expression `SeedRandom[42];` in your work. It purpose here is to ensue the same result in both cases.